# Disable going back to previous view controller from navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Setting:**

After you sign up from `SignUpViewController` you go to a `PostsViewController`. They are connected via a `show` segue, so inside the navigation bar, `< SignUp` button is automatically created.

**Problem:**

I want to hide this button because you would never have to go back to `SignUpViewController` unless you've logged out. I thought removing the view controller from the navigation stack would do the job. I did the following:

```
NSArray *navVCs = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
for (UIViewController *vc in navVCs) {
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[SignUpViewController class]]) {
        [vc removeFromParentViewController];
    }
}
```

I checked that `SignUpViewController` was correctly removed from the navigation stack, but it still doesn't remove the back button.

I also tried setting

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

and none of them remove the `< SignUp` button from the navigation bar inside `PostsViewController`.

**Solution:**

I've looked at everywhere on StackOverflow and I am surprised I couldn't find an answer. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you present the signup view modally and then transition to the posts view which would be the first view controller embedded in a nav controller?

Comment: Right now, `SignUpViewController` is the first view controller.

Comment: Yeah. But you could separate it from the posts view controller so there isn't a segue and it's not embedded in a nav controller. Once they've logged in, transition to the posts controller manually (rather than using a segue) and make sure the posts controller is the first one embedded in a nav controller.

Comment: I agree, it makes much more sense to make the `PostsViewController` the initial controller (rootViewController). Then on app startup, if you detect that the user must signup, then present the signup controller modally. Once the signup is complete and it is dismissed, the `PostsViewController` is in view.

Comment: Thank you guys. That seems a better approach to me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than disabling the back button I would recommend reviewing the design sequence of the view controllers.

Instead of a transition like this:

> NavController -> SignUp -> Posts

Try something like this

> Signup || NavController > Posts

Where the Signup view is no longer connected via a segue to the nav controller.

You could detect on app start if the signup screen is necessary and if it is present it modally (or however you wish). When the user has finished signing up you can then instantiate the Posts controller, which is embedded in a nav controller, rather than segueing to it. This way there will be no previous Signup view to return to and no back button.